# Grid System BootStrap

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Estou montado este *grid* Bootstrap, mas na última *row*, parece que a imagem dá um *margin* do próprio grid e fica desalinhada.. Minha semântica está errada?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class ="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="../img/5.png" width="100%" class="imagem-banner-destaque" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <img src="../img/2.jpg" width="100%" class="imagem-banner" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h4>Lorem ipsun </h4><span>Lorem ipsun nore inv4camus munrá</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <img src="../img/4.jpg" width="100%" class="imagem-banner" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h4>Lorem ipsun </h4><span>Lorem ipsun nore inv4camus munrá</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <img src="../img/2.jpg" width="100%" class="imagem-banner" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h4>Lorem ipsun </h4><span>Lorem ipsun nore inv4camus munrá</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <img src="../img/4.jpg" width="100%" class="imagem-banner" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h4>Lorem ipsun </h4><span>Lorem ipsun nore inv4camus munrá</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <h3>Testando o teste  !</h3>
            <span>Confira agora, todas as notícias</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <img src="../img/6.jpg" width="100%" class="imagem-banner" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                    <h4>Lorem ipsun </h4><span>Lorem ipsun nore inv4camus munrá</span>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <img src="../img/2.jpg" width="100%" class="imagem-banner" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h4>Lorem ipsun </h4><span>Lorem ipsun nore inv4camus munrá</span>
                </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Parece-me que é por causa daquele `text-left` ali no código. Experimenta tirar isso...

Comment: tirei, e ainda permanece do mesmo jeito.. todas as cols estão particionadas em 4, não sei o porque deste alinhamento estranho da imagem..

Comment: falta o  `<div class="row">` para a imagem e texto, como tem nos outros...

Comment: Se eu der outro <div class="row">, ele vai criar outra linha, esses 3 elementos tem que estar nessa row, porque são as 3 colunas na row..

Comment: Já testaste? Olha experimenta...

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo, era só implementar uma row dentro da col-xs-4, Vlwzão !

Comment: michel coloca ai, na pergunta, uma das imagens para eu testar aqui...

Comment: a imagem ta lá em cima !

Comment: Veja aqui no jsfiddle a funcionar: http://jsfiddle.net/mkmwncqr/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que eu fiz foi colocar uma `row` no em cada conjunto imagem+texto do último lance de imagens:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="row">     <!-- Adicionei esta div para juntar imagem e texto -->
        <div class="col-xs-6">
```

[Veja aqui no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkmwncqr/2/)

Comment: perfeito, funcionou certinho, Obrigado !